# Why won't GTA won't save my progress in story mode?

Tags: technical-issues, grand-theft-auto-v

My son has played GTA on this console for a couple of years with no problems.  I set up my own character recently and it has never once saved my progress.  I have passed the first couple of missions (starting over each time) but when I return I have to start again at the first mission.  Auto-save is turned on but I have also manually saved on the phone and have gone to sleep in the bed and yet it starts at the beginning each time I turn on the machine.